# How I will print the total row count in my php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a query like this:

```
$countcatid="SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfcount FROM pop_sub_sub where cat_id ='$catid'";
$rs_count=mysql_query($countcatid) or die(mysql_error());
$row_count=mysql_num_rows($rs_count);
```

How can I print the total no in my PHP page?

Comment: what? total number of records fetched?

Comment: echo mysql_num_rows($rs_count);

Comment: Well your query is wrong or your php code is wrong.  You are already asking mysql to count for you so you dont need to use mysql_num_rows to count too, this will always return 1 in the case above.

Comment: echo mysql_num_rows($rs_count)-its not working

Comment: hi John Taylor thanks for your help.Now I have rectified my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print number of rows your query fetch on the basis of condition.

```
<?php
  $countcatid="SELECT * FROM pop_sub_sub where cat_id ='$catid'";
  $rs_count=mysql_query($countcatid) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_count=mysql_num_rows($rs_count);
  echo $row_count;
?>
```

OR If you want to `echo` the `count` as column fetched from the query.

```
<?php
  $countcatid="SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfcount FROM pop_sub_sub 
  where cat_id ='$catid'";
  $rs_count=mysql_query($countcatid) or die(mysql_error());
  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $result['NumberOfcount'];
?>
```

Comment: (With a preference for the latter if the complete recordset is not required).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`mysql_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) function to retrieve the count which is stored in the first field of the first record in MySQL's resultset:

```
echo mysql_result($rs_count, 0);
```

However, as stated in the manual:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.